# Increase keyboard row key height

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I have a keyboard definition in an xml file in /res/xml which looks something like this:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:keyWidth="10%p"
          android:horizontalGap="0px"
          android:verticalGap="0px"
          android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
        >
    <Row>
        <Key... />
    </Row>
     <Row>
        <Key... />
    </Row>   

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom" >
        <Key ... />

    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

I'm looking for a way of making one row of keys taller than the others, but I can't work out how.  Increasing the keyHeight on the Keyboard tag makes all the keys bigger - is there a way to only target one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this [defaultHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Row.html#defaultHeight) which defines the default height for a key in a row..

Answer (score 1):

You can put an `android:keyHeight` property directly on a `<Row>` element, in which case it will override the keyHeight from the `<Keyboard>`. This is what I did for my project DotDash Keyboard (where one row of keys is 20% screen height, and the other is 17%).

See also:

The documentation for the `<Row>` element: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Row.html

An example of a keyboard layout with two differently sized rows: http://code.google.com/p/dotdash-keyboard-android/source/browse/res/xml/dotdash.xml